# ggplot x axis trouble

Tags: r, ggplot2

Currently, I have this plot that looks like this:

[image]

I don't like how on the x-axis there are weird lines / bars. I suspect this may be because ggplot can't fit all 540000 observations in the x axis. Here is the code I used to graph this:

```
data %>% 
  ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(x = dates_df$date, y = Quantity)) +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, hjust = 1)) +
  labs(x = "Invoice Date", y = "Quantity", title = "Quantity vs Invoice Date")
```

What can I do to get rid of / solve this mess on the x-axis?

Comment: Is `date` a factor right now?  If so, consider changing it to a `Date` and setting the axis breaks with `scale_x_date`.  Even if using a factor, you could change the number of breaks you show on the x axis.

Comment: My guess is that the issue is you are using two separate data frames (`data` and `dates_df`).  Why not combine them with a `left_join` from `dplyr`?  That should resolve quite a few issues.  Otherwise, you can use `scale_x_*`, perhaps in this case, it would be `scale_x_date()`

Comment: @aosmith `date` is a character. How do you change it to a `Date`

Comment: You can use `as.Date`.  Depending on what `date` looks like, you may  need to define what the order of years/months/days are in your date via the `format` argument.

Answer (score 0):

As was told on comments it seems there is a mess in Date column and you use of two separate data frames. As first join the data. I assume both of them has some Id or other key like name in column:

```
library("dplyr")
left_join(data,dates_df,by="id")
```

Date is also a character as was mentioned. To change it to Date, if you haven't already do this use as.Date function. After joining

```
data$date<- as.Date(data$date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```

you can find other date formats here: http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html

You said there are 540 000 observation on x axis. My suggestfion is to separate the chart for unique year. To do this use facet_grid function inside ggplot.

```
library(lubridate)    
ggplot(df, aes(x= df$date,y= df$Quantity))+ 
  geom_point() + 
  facet_grid(~year(df$date))
```

Hope it helped :)